# Google+ Login Not working properly on Android fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, google-plus, android-fragmentactivity

I am working with google+ login to my application and when i done it using a activity its work charm and after that i move my code into a fragment and after that when i try to login to google+ its not working i have to open the fragment activity 2 times to login to the google+ can anyone tell me what happen the code to the fragment is added below

```
public class GooglePluseFragment extends Fragment implements
        ConnectionCallbacks, OnConnectionFailedListener {

private static final int RC_SIGN_IN = 0;

private static final String TAG = "MainActivity";

private static final int PROFILE_PIC_SIZE = 800;

private GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;

private boolean mIntentInProgress;

private boolean mSignInClicked;

private ConnectionResult mConnectionResult;

private SignInButton btnSignIn;
private Button btnSignOut;

private Context mContext;
private Activity mActivity;



@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    mActivity = getActivity();
    mContext = getActivity().getApplicationContext();
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.compund_google_pluse_fragment,
            container, false);

    btnSignIn = (SignInButton) view.findViewById(R.id.btn_sign_in);
    btnSignOut = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.btn_sign_out);

    sharedPref = view.getContext().getSharedPreferences(
            Constantz.SHEARED_PREFEREANCE, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

    mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(view.getContext())
            .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
            .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this).addApi(Plus.API, null)
            .addScope(Plus.SCOPE_PLUS_LOGIN).build();

    btnSignIn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            signInWithGplus();

        }
    });

    btnSignOut.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            signOutFromGplus();
        }
    });

    return view;
}

@Override
public void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    mGoogleApiClient.connect();
}

@Override
public void onStop() {
    super.onStop();
    if (mGoogleApiClient.isConnected()) {
        mGoogleApiClient.disconnect();
    }
}

@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int responseCode,
        Intent intent) {

    if (requestCode == RC_SIGN_IN) {
        if (responseCode != Activity.RESULT_OK) {
            mSignInClicked = false;
        }

        mIntentInProgress = false;

        if (!mGoogleApiClient.isConnecting()) {
            mGoogleApiClient.connect();

        }
    }
}

@Override
public void onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult result) {
    if (!result.hasResolution()) {
        GooglePlayServicesUtil.getErrorDialog(result.getErrorCode(),
                mActivity, 0).show();
        Log.e(TAG, "" + result.getErrorCode());
        return;
    }

    if (!mIntentInProgress) {

        mConnectionResult = result;

        if (mSignInClicked) {

            Log.e(TAG, "" + result.getErrorCode());
            resolveSignInError();
        }
    }

}

@Override
public void onConnected(Bundle arg0) {
    mSignInClicked = false;

    getProfileInformation();

    updateUI(true);

}

@Override
public void onConnectionSuspended(int arg0) {
    mGoogleApiClient.connect();
    updateUI(false);

}

private void updateUI(boolean isSignedIn) {
    if (isSignedIn) {
        btnSignIn.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        btnSignOut.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

    } else {
        btnSignIn.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        btnSignOut.setVisibility(View.GONE);

    }
}

/**
 * Sign-in into google
 * */
private void signInWithGplus() {
    if (!mGoogleApiClient.isConnecting()) {
        mSignInClicked = true;
        resolveSignInError();
    }
}

/**
 * Method to resolve any signin errors
 * */
private void resolveSignInError() {
    if (mConnectionResult.hasResolution()) {
        try {
            mIntentInProgress = true;
            mConnectionResult.startResolutionForResult(mActivity,
                    RC_SIGN_IN);
        } catch (SendIntentException e) {
            mIntentInProgress = false;
            mGoogleApiClient.connect();
        }
    }
}

/**
 * Fetching user's information name, email, profile pic
 * */
private void getProfileInformation() {
    try {
        if (Plus.PeopleApi.getCurrentPerson(mGoogleApiClient) != null) {
            Person currentPerson = Plus.PeopleApi
                    .getCurrentPerson(mGoogleApiClient);
            String personName = currentPerson.getDisplayName();
            String personPhotoUrl = currentPerson.getImage().getUrl();
            String personGooglePlusProfile = currentPerson.getUrl();
            String email = Plus.AccountApi.getAccountName(mGoogleApiClient);

            Log.e(TAG, "Name: " + personName + ", plusProfile: "
                    + personGooglePlusProfile + ", email: " + email
                    + ", Image: " + personPhotoUrl + " user id:"
                    + currentPerson.getId());






        } else {
            Toast.makeText(mContext, "Person information is null",
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

/**
 * Sign-out from google
 * */
private void signOutFromGplus() {
    if (mGoogleApiClient.isConnected()) {
        Plus.AccountApi.clearDefaultAccount(mGoogleApiClient);
        mGoogleApiClient.disconnect();
        mGoogleApiClient.connect();

        updateUI(false);

    }
}
```

}

this is how i added framgent in the fragment activity

```
pluseFragment = new GooglePluseFragment();

        FragmentManager manager = getSupportFragmentManager();

        FragmentTransaction transaction = manager.beginTransaction();
transaction.add(R.id.pluse_frame_layout, pluseFragment);
transaction.commit();
```

can somebody tell me what i have done wrong ? why i have to open the activity two times to login thank you

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Finally found the answer, Problem was when the result activity call in the fragment was catch by the parent activity so you have to manually redirect the result to your fragment. Just have to add this line in your Parent Fragment Activity

```
@Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

        if (requestCode == GooglePluseFragment.RC_SIGN_IN) {
            GooglePluseFragment fragment = (GooglePluseFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
                    .findFragmentById(R.id.pluse_frame_layout);
            fragment.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        } else {
            super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        }
    }
```

Comment: where you are declaring this id? pluse_frame_layout

Comment: `<FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/pluse_frame_layout"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/fb_frame_layout" >
    </FrameLayout>`

Answer (score 0):

Easy Solution for this ::
just create the static method in fragment 
"

```
public static myOnActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data){
.....Enter same code
}
```

and

call this method from Parant Activity on

```
     protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

.....
MyFragment.myOnActivityResult(requestCode,resultCode,data)

}
```

thats it