# LocationSettingsRequest dialog to enable GPS - onActivityResult() skipped

Tags: android, dialog

Part of my app requires location services, so if location is currently turned off, the app will prompt the user to enable it. [Here](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/location/SettingsApi) is how I am doing it: (Also seen in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29872703/3558874) Stack Overflow answer)

```
LocationSettingsRequest.Builder builder = new LocationSettingsRequest.Builder()
            .addLocationRequest(mLocationRequest);
builder.setAlwaysShow(true);

PendingResult<LocationSettingsResult> result = LocationServices.SettingsApi.checkLocationSettings(mGoogleApiClient, builder.build());

result.setResultCallback(new ResultCallback<LocationSettingsResult>() 
{
     @Override
     public void onResult(LocationSettingsResult result) 
     {
         final Status status = result.getStatus();
         final LocationSettingsStates = result.getLocationSettingsStates();
         switch (status.getStatusCode()) 
         {
             case LocationSettingsStatusCodes.SUCCESS:
                 // All location settings are satisfied. The client can initialize location
                 // requests here.
                 ...
                 Log.d("onResult", "SUCCESS");
                 break;
             case LocationSettingsStatusCodes.RESOLUTION_REQUIRED:
                 // Location settings are not satisfied. But could be fixed by showing the user
                 // a dialog.
                 Log.d("onResult", "RESOLUTION_REQUIRED");
                 try 
                 {
                     // Show the dialog by calling startResolutionForResult(),
                     // and check the result in onActivityResult().
                     status.startResolutionForResult(OuterClass.this, REQUEST_LOCATION);
                 } 
                 catch (SendIntentException e) 
                 {
                     // Ignore the error.
                 }
                 break;
             case LocationSettingsStatusCodes.SETTINGS_CHANGE_UNAVAILABLE:
                 // Location settings are not satisfied. However, we have no way to fix the
                 // settings so we won't show the dialog.
                 ...
                 Log.d("onResult", "UNAVAILABLE");
                 break;
         }
     }
 });

@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data)
{
    // This log is never called
    Log.d("onActivityResult()", Integer.toString(resultCode));

    final LocationSettingsStates states = LocationSettingsStates.fromIntent(data);
    switch (requestCode)
    {
        case REQUEST_LOCATION:
            switch (resultCode)
            {
                case Activity.RESULT_OK:
                {
                    // All required changes were successfully made
                    break;
                }
                case Activity.RESULT_CANCELED:
                {
                    // The user was asked to change settings, but chose not to
                    break;
                }
                default:
                {      
                    break;
                }
            }
            break;
    }
}
```

This code works well, however, `onActivityResult()` is always skipped. Whether or not the user presses `Yes`, `No`, or `back` from the `Dialog`, `onActivityResult()` doesn't run.

I need Android to call `onActivityResult()` so if the user chooses not to turn on location services, I can handle it appropriately.

Google's developer page (and the code above) explicitly says that `onActivityResult()` should be called. Anyone know why it's being skipped?

I also don't know what the purpose of this line is:

`final LocationSettingsStates states = LocationSettingsStates.fromIntent(data);`

Thanks!

Edit: Basic information on the structure of my app:

- This code is contained within the `onResume()` method of a `Fragment` which implements `GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks`,                                                `GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener`, and `LocationListener` to receive location updates. Example seen [here](https://developer.android.com/intl/zh-CN/training/location/receive-location-updates.html).
- In `onLocationChanged()` the `Fragment` will have a custom `View` call `invalidate()` and re-draw itself with updated information.

Answer (score 154, accepted):

**UPDATE**

The original answer below is using Java and the now deprecated [SettingsApi](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/location/SettingsApi).

Here is a more modern approach using Kotlin and [SettingsClient](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/location/SettingsClient):

```
fun showEnableLocationSetting() {
    activity?.let {
        val locationRequest = LocationRequest.create()
        locationRequest.priority = LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY

        val builder = LocationSettingsRequest.Builder()
                .addLocationRequest(locationRequest)

        val task = LocationServices.getSettingsClient(it)
                .checkLocationSettings(builder.build())

        task.addOnSuccessListener { response ->
            val states = response.locationSettingsStates
            if (states.isLocationPresent) {
                //Do something
            }
        }
        task.addOnFailureListener { e ->
            if (e is ResolvableApiException) {
                try {
                    // Handle result in onActivityResult()
                    e.startResolutionForResult(it,
                            MainActivity.LOCATION_SETTING_REQUEST)
                } catch (sendEx: IntentSender.SendIntentException) { }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

In MainActivity, define the constant:

```
companion object {
    const val LOCATION_SETTING_REQUEST = 999
}
```

**ORIGINAL ANSWER:**

It looks like the main issue is that you have all of the code in a Fragment, and since `startResolutionForResult()` needs an Activity passed into it, the Activity is what gets the `onActivityResult()` callback.

One way to get around that is to use the technique described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22602988/google-login-not-working-properly-on-android-fragment), manually call the Fragment's `onActivityResult()` method from the Activity when the result comes in.

I just got this simple example working.

First, the Activity, which adds the Fragment, and also has functionality to pass along the result of `onActivityResult()` to the Fragment:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity{

    LocationFragment lFrag;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        lFrag = LocationFragment.newInstance();
        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(R.id.fragment_container, lFrag).commit();

    }
    
    @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        if (requestCode == LocationFragment.REQUEST_LOCATION){
            lFrag.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        }
        else {
            super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the Fragment, which contains all of the functionality to show the dialog, and handle the result.  In this simple example I just used Toast messages to verify that it is working as expected.  Note that the main change that I've made here from the code in your question is the use of `getActivity()` to get the Activity reference needed for the call to `startResolutionForResult()`.

```
public class LocationFragment extends Fragment
        implements GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks,
        GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener {


    LocationRequest mLocationRequest;
    GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;
    PendingResult<LocationSettingsResult> result;
    final static int REQUEST_LOCATION = 199;

    public static LocationFragment newInstance() {
        LocationFragment fragment = new LocationFragment();
        return fragment;
    }

    public LocationFragment() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(getActivity())
                .addApi(LocationServices.API)
                .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
                .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this).build();
        mGoogleApiClient.connect();

        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_location, container, false);
    }


    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnected(Bundle bundle) {

        mLocationRequest = LocationRequest.create();
        mLocationRequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY);
        mLocationRequest.setInterval(30 * 1000);
        mLocationRequest.setFastestInterval(5 * 1000);

        LocationSettingsRequest.Builder builder = new LocationSettingsRequest.Builder()
                .addLocationRequest(mLocationRequest);
        builder.setAlwaysShow(true);

        result = LocationServices.SettingsApi.checkLocationSettings(mGoogleApiClient, builder.build());

        result.setResultCallback(new ResultCallback<LocationSettingsResult>() {
            @Override
            public void onResult(LocationSettingsResult result) {
                final Status status = result.getStatus();
                //final LocationSettingsStates state = result.getLocationSettingsStates();
                switch (status.getStatusCode()) {
                    case LocationSettingsStatusCodes.SUCCESS:
                        // All location settings are satisfied. The client can initialize location
                        // requests here.
                        //...
                        break;
                    case LocationSettingsStatusCodes.RESOLUTION_REQUIRED:
                        // Location settings are not satisfied. But could be fixed by showing the user
                        // a dialog.
                        try {
                            // Show the dialog by calling startResolutionForResult(),
                            // and check the result in onActivityResult().
                            status.startResolutionForResult(
                                    getActivity(),
                                    REQUEST_LOCATION);
                        } catch (IntentSender.SendIntentException e) {
                            // Ignore the error.
                        }
                        break;
                    case LocationSettingsStatusCodes.SETTINGS_CHANGE_UNAVAILABLE:
                        // Location settings are not satisfied. However, we have no way to fix the
                        // settings so we won't show the dialog.
                        //...
                        break;
                }
            }
        });

    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data)
    {
        Log.d("onActivityResult()", Integer.toString(resultCode));

        //final LocationSettingsStates states = LocationSettingsStates.fromIntent(data);
        switch (requestCode)
        {
            case REQUEST_LOCATION:
                switch (resultCode)
                {
                    case Activity.RESULT_OK:
                    {
                        // All required changes were successfully made
                        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Location enabled by user!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        break;
                    }
                    case Activity.RESULT_CANCELED:
                    {
                        // The user was asked to change settings, but chose not to
                        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Location not enabled, user cancelled.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        break;
                    }
                    default:
                    {
                        break;
                    }
                }
                break;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionSuspended(int i) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult connectionResult) {

    }

}
```

Here are the results visually, first the dialog is shown if Location Mode is disabled:

[image]

Then, if the user clicks No, the result is passed from the Activity to the Fragment, which shows a Toast:

[image]

Same thing when the user clicks Yes, but with a success result, and Location Mode is enabled:

[image]

Note that it might be a better option to just keep all of this functionality in the Activity, and then call into a public method in the Fragment when the result comes in.

Here is fully working code for keeping the functionality in the Activity.
Of course in this solution, you would need to add a call into the Fragment to update the state of Location Mode after `onActivityResult()` is called.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity
        implements GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks,
        GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener {


    LocationRequest mLocationRequest;
    GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;
    PendingResult<LocationSettingsResult> result;
    final static int REQUEST_LOCATION = 199;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
                .addApi(LocationServices.API)
                .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
                .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this).build();
        mGoogleApiClient.connect();

    }

    @Override
    public void onConnected(Bundle bundle) {

        mLocationRequest = LocationRequest.create();
        mLocationRequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY);
        mLocationRequest.setInterval(30 * 1000);
        mLocationRequest.setFastestInterval(5 * 1000);

        LocationSettingsRequest.Builder builder = new LocationSettingsRequest.Builder()
                .addLocationRequest(mLocationRequest);
        builder.setAlwaysShow(true);

        result = LocationServices.SettingsApi.checkLocationSettings(mGoogleApiClient, builder.build());

        result.setResultCallback(new ResultCallback<LocationSettingsResult>() {
            @Override
            public void onResult(LocationSettingsResult result) {
                final Status status = result.getStatus();
                //final LocationSettingsStates state = result.getLocationSettingsStates();
                switch (status.getStatusCode()) {
                    case LocationSettingsStatusCodes.SUCCESS:
                        // All location settings are satisfied. The client can initialize location
                        // requests here.
                        //...
                        break;
                    case LocationSettingsStatusCodes.RESOLUTION_REQUIRED:
                        // Location settings are not satisfied. But could be fixed by showing the user
                        // a dialog.
                        try {
                            // Show the dialog by calling startResolutionForResult(),
                            // and check the result in onActivityResult().
                            status.startResolutionForResult(
                                    MainActivity.this,
                                    REQUEST_LOCATION);
                        } catch (SendIntentException e) {
                            // Ignore the error.
                        }
                        break;
                    case LocationSettingsStatusCodes.SETTINGS_CHANGE_UNAVAILABLE:
                        // Location settings are not satisfied. However, we have no way to fix the
                        // settings so we won't show the dialog.
                        //...
                        break;
                }
            }
        });

    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data)
    {
        Log.d("onActivityResult()", Integer.toString(resultCode));

        //final LocationSettingsStates states = LocationSettingsStates.fromIntent(data);
        switch (requestCode)
        {
            case REQUEST_LOCATION:
                switch (resultCode)
                {
                    case Activity.RESULT_OK:
                    {
                        // All required changes were successfully made
                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Location enabled by user!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        break;
                    }
                    case Activity.RESULT_CANCELED:
                    {
                        // The user was asked to change settings, but chose not to
                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Location not enabled, user cancelled.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        break;
                    }
                    default:
                    {
                        break;
                    }
                }
                break;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionSuspended(int i) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult connectionResult) {

    }
}
```

Comment: How to refresh the location on ActivityResult

Comment: You will need to request location updates once the user has enabled location services.  See here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34582370/how-can-i-use-google-maps-and-locationmanager-to-show-current-location-on-androi

Comment: Hi @DanielNugent thanks for the post. I have a situation where I am checking if the user's settings are as expected every time i click on a button. Which simply means, I am calling result.setResultCallback every time to check if the user has changed the setting. Strangely, this works only first time. onResult will never get called . i have a SO question on the same http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38151650/android-fusedlocations-settingsapi-does-not-work-more-than-once. can you please help

Comment: One of the fine answers for 6.0 devices. However, I am calling LocationFragment inside another fragment & not getting Toast at all. Will you please tell me the problem?

Comment: Also, if I try the same code with Activity/Fragment then it works fine but fragment to fragment it doesn't Toast

Comment: @vvb The result must be handled in the Activity

Comment: I've wrapped the solution in a library. More info about that in my answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/41268698/2534351

Comment: I've called a helper method, which has **onActivityResult** but the helper class method is skipped and activity's **onActivityResult** is called

Comment: it is returning 0 every time

Comment: If the user turned on location from this dialog and then turned Off from the top menu then again try to turn on location from app this dialog is didn't shown next time.

Comment: @Daniel Nugent, According to what i understood, LocationSettingRequest check is done only once before requesting for location updates right ?? After starting request for location updates, after some time if the user disable the gps, will the LocationSettinsRequest onFailureCallback() gets called again ?? I think this is one time call back to check if gps is ON before requesting for location updates. What we can do if user turns OFF gps after some time ?? may be we should periodically check if gps is turned ON.

Comment: @Daniel Nugent, Can we call LocationSettingRequest from a foreground service ?? Because i'm requesting for location updates from a foreground serrvice.

Comment: @PradeepkumarReddy It sounds like the best solution for you would be to incorporate a listener on the Location settings, see here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36325088/how-to-listen-for-location-setting-being-turned-on-android-app

Answer (score 42):

You need to add this to your result callback:

```
case LocationSettingsStatusCodes.RESOLUTION_REQUIRED:
    try {
        fragment.startIntentSenderForResult(status.getResolution().getIntentSender(), REQUEST_CHECK_SETTINGS, null, 0, 0, 0, null);
    } catch (IntentSender.SendIntentException e) {
        // Ignore the error.
    }
    break;
```

`onActivityResult` will be called on your fragment, you don't need to call it manually in your activity. This is essentially how `startResolutionForResult` works.

Comment: please add backticks wrappers around your inline code bit

Comment: I had commented this line : status.startResolutionForResult(hostActivity, REQUEST_CHECK_SETTINGS); and used your code and its working without having to override onActiivtyResult in main activity.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. working perfectly.

Comment: You can jump into the source for Status.startResolutionForResult also and verify that this is exactly what it's doing. Probably a good idea to also make the same check for Status.hasResolution also though.

Comment: Can we call LocationSettingRequest from a foreground service ?? Because i'm requesting for location updates from a foreground serrvice.

Comment: `startIntentSenderForResult` is now deprecated. Use `registerForActivityResult`.

Answer (score 16):

When you need to resolve the `Status` or the `ResolvableApiException`, I suggest you to leverage the `activity.registerForActivityResult` API in place of `startResolutionForResult`:

```java
ActivityResultLauncher<IntentSenderRequest> launcher = activity.registerForActivityResult(
        new ActivityResultContracts.StartIntentSenderForResult(),
        new ActivityResultCallback<ActivityResult>() {
            @Override
            public void onActivityResult(ActivityResult result) {
                if (result.getResultCode() == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
                    // All required changes were successfully made
                } else {
                    // The user was asked to change settings, but chose not to
                }
            }
        });

IntentSenderRequest intentSenderRequest = new IntentSenderRequest.Builder(exception.getResolution()).build();
launcher.launch(intentSenderRequest);
```

You are using Java, but in case Kotlin is needed:

```kotlin
val launcher = activity.registerForActivityResult(ActivityResultContracts.StartIntentSenderForResult()) { result ->
        if (result.resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
            // User accepted
        } else {
            // User didn't accepted
        }
    }

val intentSenderRequest = IntentSenderRequest.Builder(exception.resolution).build()
launcher.launch(intentSenderRequest)
```

Comment: exactly what I was searching, how to leverage the activity result API for this, so this whole location fetch, permission check, settings can fit in one extension function and I simply call it from wherever I need..no fus

Comment: This should be mark now as an answer, the old marked answer was too outdated. This is the latest approach as of this moment.

Answer (score 5):

If you want results back to your fragment than use

```
startIntentSenderForResult(status.getResolution().getIntentSender(), REQUEST_CODE_LOCATION_SETTING, null, 0, 0, 0, null);
```

instead of `status.startResolutionForResult(YourActivity, LOCATION_REQUEST);`

USING above method will deliver result back to your fragment only.

Comment: Thanks, but this is a copy of Saša Tarbuk answer (https://stackoverflow.com/a/39579124/2914140).

Comment: Can we call LocationSettingRequest from a foreground service ?? Because i'm requesting for location updates from a foreground serrvice.

Comment: @user3410835 No you can't.

Comment: @Ghodasara Bhaumik. Thanks. reason ??

Comment: @user3410835 because to enable location android has to show dialog and to show dialog it needs context of your app. If app has fore ground service running means app is not up and android can't find context of your app to show Location Enable Dialog.

Answer (score 4):

**For Kotlin Users**

This solution is applicable for both `Activity` and `Fragment` by doing one following change in `checkLocationSetting()`:

**For Activity** `resolvableApiException.startResolutionForResult(this@MainActivity, REQUEST_CHECK_SETTING)`

**For Fragment**
`startIntentSenderForResult(resolvableApiException.resolution.intentSender, REQUEST_CHECK_SETTING, null, 0, 0,0,null)`

By using [LocationSettingsResponse](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/location/LocationSettingsResponse) this task can be achieved.

inside [MainActivity.kt](https://gist.github.com/ShoaibKakal/4d07b4001e34cb770d3ee7cae294f7b0)

```
    private fun checkLocationSetting()
        {
            locationRequest = LocationRequest.create()
            locationRequest.apply {
                priority=LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY
                interval = 5000
                fastestInterval = 2000
            }
    
            val builder = LocationSettingsRequest.Builder()
                .addLocationRequest(locationRequest)
            builder.setAlwaysShow(true)
    
            val result: Task<LocationSettingsResponse> = LocationServices.getSettingsClient(applicationContext)
                .checkLocationSettings(builder.build())
    
            result.addOnCompleteListener {
                try{
                    val response: LocationSettingsResponse = it.getResult(ApiException::class.java)
                    Toast.makeText(this@MainActivity, "GPS is On", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                    Log.d(TAG, "checkSetting: GPS On")
                }catch(e:ApiException){
    
                    when(e.statusCode){
                        LocationSettingsStatusCodes.RESOLUTION_REQUIRED ->{
                            val resolvableApiException = e as ResolvableApiException
                            resolvableApiException.startResolutionForResult(this@MainActivity, REQUEST_CHECK_SETTING)
                            Log.d(TAG, "checkSetting: RESOLUTION_REQUIRED")
                        }
    
                        LocationSettingsStatusCodes.SETTINGS_CHANGE_UNAVAILABLE -> {
                            // USER DEVICE DOES NOT HAVE LOCATION OPTION
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

**onActivityResult**

```
 override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent?) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data)
        when(requestCode)
        {
            REQUEST_CHECK_SETTING ->{
                when(resultCode){
                    Activity.RESULT_OK->{
                        Toast.makeText(this@MainActivity, "GPS is Turned on", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                    }
                    Activity.RESULT_CANCELED ->{
                        Toast.makeText(this@MainActivity, "GPS is Required to use this app", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Link to complete code [MainActivity.kt](https://gist.github.com/ShoaibKakal/4d07b4001e34cb770d3ee7cae294f7b0)

**Output:**

[image]
[image]

Link to complete code [MainActivity.kt](https://gist.github.com/ShoaibKakal/4d07b4001e34cb770d3ee7cae294f7b0)

Comment: REQUEST_CHECK_SETTING is not getting imported for me...

Comment: it's a constant. you can declare it yourself.

Comment: here is the link to mainActivity.java: https://gist.github.com/ShoaibKakal/4d07b4001e34cb770d3ee7cae294f7b0

Answer (score 1):

For handling enable location from fragment below is the latest code that can be used. Settings API is now deprecated. Below is the method to use SettingsClient API.

Also I noticed that, in Android 10 devices even when user enable the location; status result in onActivityResult is coming as RESULT_CANCELED, I couldn't find a way to get rid of that issue in Android 10 device where as in Android PIE the result code is RESULT_OK. So only way to detect whether user enabled it or not is by explicitly checking whether location is enabled using LocationManagerCompat API for Android 10 devices

```
private fun enableLocationIfRequired() {
    val builder = LocationSettingsRequest.Builder()
        .addLocationRequest(LocationRequest().setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY))
        .setAlwaysShow(true)

    val settingsClient = LocationServices.getSettingsClient(context!!)

    val task = settingsClient!!.checkLocationSettings(builder.build())
    task.addOnCompleteListener {
        try {
            val response = it.getResult(ApiException::class.java)

            //Success
            Log.d(javaClass.simpleName, "Location is enabled")

        } catch (exception: ApiException) {
            Log.d(javaClass.simpleName, "exception thrown: ${exception.statusCode}")
            when (exception.statusCode) {
                LocationSettingsStatusCodes.RESOLUTION_REQUIRED -> {
                    // Location settings are not satisfied. But could be fixed by showing the
                    // user a dialog.
                    try {
                        // Cast to a resolvable exception.
                        val resolvable = exception as ResolvableApiException
                        // Show the dialog by calling startResolutionForResult(),
                        // and check the result in onActivityResult().
                        Log.d(javaClass.simpleName, "startResolutionForResult called")

                        this.startIntentSenderForResult(
                            resolvable.resolution.intentSender,
                            RC_LOCATION_ENABLE,
                            null, 0, 0, 0, null
                        )

                    } catch (e: IntentSender.SendIntentException) {
                        // Ignore the error.
                        Log.d(javaClass.simpleName, "IntentSender.SendIntentException")
                    } catch (e: ClassCastException) {
                        // Ignore, should be an impossible error.
                        Log.d(javaClass.simpleName, "ClassCastException")
                    }
                }
                LocationSettingsStatusCodes.SETTINGS_CHANGE_UNAVAILABLE -> {
                    // Location settings are not satisfied. However, we have no way to fix the
                    // settings so we won't show the dialog.
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent?) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data)
    when (requestCode) {
        RC_LOCATION_ENABLE -> {
            if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
                Log.d(javaClass.simpleName, "Location is enabled by user")
            } else {
                Log.d(javaClass.simpleName, "Location enable request is cancelled by user")
            }
            val lm = context!!.getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE) as LocationManager
            if (LocationManagerCompat.isLocationEnabled(lm)) {
                Log.d(javaClass.simpleName, "Location is enabled by user")
            } else {
                Log.d(javaClass.simpleName, "Location enable request is cancelled by user")
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to @gianlucaparadise [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63296913/2914140) you should write for new API:

Fragment (or maybe Activity):

```
private lateinit var checkLocationSettings: ActivityResultLauncher<IntentSenderRequest>

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    checkLocationSettings = 
        registerForActivityResult(ActivityResultContracts.StartIntentSenderForResult()) { result ->
            if (result.resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                // GPS is turned on in system settings.
            }
    }
}
```

Fragment or utility class where you want to enable GPS (see [1](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58539680/2914140) or [2](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31816683/2914140)):

```
.addOnFailureListener(context) { e ->
    when ((e as? ApiException)?.statusCode) {
        LocationSettingsStatusCodes.RESOLUTION_REQUIRED ->
            try {
                // Cast to a resolvable exception.
                val resolvable = e as ResolvableApiException
                // Old API: show the dialog by calling startResolutionForResult(),
                // and check the result in onActivityResult().
                // New API: call registerForActivityResult::launch
                // and check the result in callback.
                val intentSenderRequest =
                    IntentSenderRequest.Builder(resolvable.resolution).build()
                checkLocationSettings.launch(intentSenderRequest)
            } catch (sie: IntentSender.SendIntentException) {
                Timber.e("GPS: Unable to execute request.")
            } catch (cce: java.lang.ClassCastException) {
                // Ignore, should be an impossible error.
                Timber.e("GPS: Unable to execute request, ClassCastException.")
            }
```

Deprecated API variant for Fragment and `onActivityResult`: [LocationSettingsRequest dialog to enable GPS - onActivityResult() skipped](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31235564/locationsettingsrequest-dialog-to-enable-gps-onactivityresult-skipped/39579124#39579124).

Comment: Any source that says `startResolutionForResult ` is the old and `registerForActivityResult ` is newer?

Comment: @Dr.jacky, sorry, I don't have this project now. I used `startResolutionForResult` and `registerForActivityResult`, the first one didn't lead to a result in a fragment or was deprecated (I don't remember).

Comment: @Dr.jacky, please, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67983163/startintentsenderforresult-deprecated-android, https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/fragment#1.3.0-alpha05. I meant fragments, in activities `startResolutionForResult` is still used (https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity#startIntentSenderForResult(android.content.IntentSender,%20int,%20android.content.Intent,%20int,%20int,%20int,%20android.os.Bundle). Also `onActivityResult` is deprecated.

Answer (score 0):

I see that you use different constants `REQUEST_CHECK_SETTINGS` and `REQUEST_LOCATION` for request code. Do they have same value?

For the code:`final LocationSettingsStates states = LocationSettingsStates.fromIntent(intent);`. 
The purpose of above code is to get the current status of Location setting(like use Network, GPS, ...) after changed the setting. 
Also, in your code, I think it's should be `LocationSettingsStates.fromIntent(data);` because the `intent` doesn't exixst here, maybe it's just a typo.

Comment: Thanks. For this question, I copied the code directly from Google's developer pages. Those errors were not present in my app, but they weren't the problem anyway. If you look at `onActivityResult()` now, you'll see a `Log` function that is never even called.

Answer (score 0):

Its because of all google api codes present in the Fragments.. Try the following it will help to overcome...

1.Create a empty constructor for your fragments.

2.need oncreate() method before the onCreateView()...

3.paste the Google api code inside the oncreate()....

```
    public mainFragment(){

}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    try {
        buildGoogleApiClient();
        buildLocationSettingsRequest();

        checkLocationSettings();
        mGoogleApiClient.connect();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

> For your Reference...

[Click here...](https://github.com/9tarz/shoutout_android/blob/master/app/src/main/java/activity/HomeFragment.java)

Answer (score 0):

Saving fragment field in activity (as Daniel suggested) is not often a good decision, cause imagine you have multiple fragments and each contains location code. I did it in a different manner:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements PlaceFragment.SettingsModifyHandler {

    private static final int LOCATION_SETTINGS_RESULT = 1;
    private OnResultCallback placeCallback;

    ...

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if (requestCode == LOCATION_SETTINGS_RESULT) {
            if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
                placeCallback.resultOk();
            } else {
                placeCallback.resultFail();
            }
        placeCallback = null;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void handle(IntentSender intentSender, OnResultCallback callback) {
        placeCallback = callback;
        try {
            startIntentSenderForResult(intentSender, LOCATION_SETTINGS_RESULT, null, 0, 0, 0);
        } catch (IntentSender.SendIntentException e) {
            callback.resultFail();
        }
    }
}

public class PlaceFragment extends Fragment {

    private SettingsModifyHandler settingsModifyHandler;

    ...

    @Override
    public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
        super.onAttach(activity);
        if (context instanceof SettingsModifyHandler) {
            settingsModifyHandler = (SettingsModifyHandler) context;
        } else {
            throw new RuntimeException("Parent activity must implement PlaceFragment.SettingsModifyHandler interface");
        }
    }

    /* Callback from module, where you implemented status.getStatusCode().LocationSettingsStatusCodes.RESOLUTION_REQUIRED case
    (status is instance of com.google.android.gms.common.api.Status)
    You provide intentSender here through status.getResolution().getIntentSender() */
    @Override
    public void placeLoadError(IntentSender sender) {
        TextView view_text = (TextView) root.findViewById(R.id.text_error);
        TextView view_btn = (TextView) root.findViewById(R.id.btn_reply);

        view_text.setText("Need to change location settings");
        view_btn.setText("Change");
        view_btn.setOnClickListener(v -> {
            settingsModifyHandler.handle(sender, new SettingsModifyHandler.OnResultCallback() {
                @Override
                public void resultOk() {
                    presenter.loadPlace(placeId);
                }

                @Override
                public void resultFail() {
                    ToastUtils.show("You should change location settings!");
                }
            });
        });
    }

    public interface SettingsModifyHandler {
        void handle(IntentSender intentSender, OnResultCallback callback);

        interface OnResultCallback {
            void resultOk();
            void resultFail();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data)
```

Needs to be called as first thing in onActivityResult...