# Turn GPS on programmatically like Ola Cabs Android app

Tags: android, gps, location-services

I am working on an application and need to integrate GPS location. I want to switch the GPS on programmatically. The condition is: I don't want to send the user to the Setting panel to enable it. I want to enable it forcefully or a single prompt will work (similar to the Ola Cabs Android app). A lot of questions are for this on this site but everyone is looking for the similar functionality like Ola Cabs app. So I have started this thread so that it can be clear for all of us.

Comment: if there is no such way using official SDK, then pleasdy dont try to cheat the system

Comment: Single prompt: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31235564/locationsettingsrequest-dialog-onactivityresult-skipped/31816683#31816683

Answer (score 12):

Here is my 100% working code first add this dependencie `compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:9.2.1'` to your build.gradle(Module: app)

After that create class with name `StartLocationAlert.java` and copy this code and paste in this file

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.IntentSender;
import android.net.wifi.WifiManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.example.googlemappromt.MainActivity;
import com.google.android.gms.common.ConnectionResult;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.PendingResult;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.ResultCallback;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.Status;

import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationRequest;
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationServices;
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationSettingsRequest;
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationSettingsResult;
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationSettingsStates;
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationSettingsStatusCodes;
import com.google.android.gms.vision.barcode.Barcode;


/**
 * Created by Anirudh on 20/07/16.
 */
public class StartLocationAlert implements GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks, GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener  {
    Activity context;
    protected static final int REQUEST_CHECK_SETTINGS = 0x1;
    GoogleApiClient googleApiClient;
    public StartLocationAlert(Activity context) {
        this.context = context;
        googleApiClient = getInstance();
        if(googleApiClient != null){
            //googleApiClient.connect();
            settingsrequest();
            googleApiClient.connect();
        }
    }

    public  GoogleApiClient getInstance(){
        GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(context).addConnectionCallbacks(this).addOnConnectionFailedListener(this).addApi(LocationServices.API).build();
        return mGoogleApiClient;
    }

    public void settingsrequest()
    {
        Log.e("settingsrequest","Comes");


        LocationRequest locationRequest = LocationRequest.create();
        locationRequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY);
        locationRequest.setInterval(30 * 1000);
        locationRequest.setFastestInterval(5 * 1000);
        LocationSettingsRequest.Builder builder = new LocationSettingsRequest.Builder()
                .addLocationRequest(locationRequest);
        builder.setAlwaysShow(true); //this is the key ingredient

        PendingResult<LocationSettingsResult> result =
                LocationServices.SettingsApi.checkLocationSettings(googleApiClient, builder.build());
        result.setResultCallback(new ResultCallback<LocationSettingsResult>() {
            @Override
            public void onResult(LocationSettingsResult result) {
                final Status status = result.getStatus();
                final LocationSettingsStates state = result.getLocationSettingsStates();
                switch (status.getStatusCode()) {
                    case LocationSettingsStatusCodes.SUCCESS:
                        // All location settings are satisfied. The client can initialize location
                        // requests here.
                       // Log.e("Application","Button Clicked");
                        break;
                    case LocationSettingsStatusCodes.RESOLUTION_REQUIRED:
                        // Location settings are not satisfied. But could be fixed by showing the user
                        // a dialog.
                       // Log.e("Application","Button Clicked1");
                        try {
                            // Show the dialog by calling startResolutionForResult(),
                            // and check the result in onActivityResult().
                            status.startResolutionForResult(context, REQUEST_CHECK_SETTINGS);
                        } catch (IntentSender.SendIntentException e) {
                            // Ignore the error.
                            Log.e("Applicationsett",e.toString());
                        }
                        break;
                    case LocationSettingsStatusCodes.SETTINGS_CHANGE_UNAVAILABLE:
                        // Location settings are not satisfied. However, we have no way to fix the
                        // settings so we won't show the dialog.
                        //Log.e("Application","Button Clicked2");
                        Toast.makeText(context, "Location is Enabled", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        break;
                }
            }
        });
    }


    @Override
    public void onConnected(@Nullable Bundle bundle) {


    /*    MainActivity mm = new MainActivity();
        mm.requestLocationUpdates();*/
        Toast.makeText(context , "Connected", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionSuspended(int i) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionFailed(@NonNull ConnectionResult connectionResult) {

    }
}
```

Usage of this above class is show below

```
 @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        Activity mContext = MainActivity.this //change this your activity name 
        StartLocationAlert startLocationAlert = new StartLocationAlert(mContext);

       requestLocationUpdates();

    }
```

And don't forget to add below permissions in `AndroidManifest.xml` file or else this might not work properly

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
```

Hope this might help you..

Comment: It is to start updating location after turning gps on I have just put the usage of u want entire project add comment with your email Id I'll forward it to you  I dint put that function body cause though it's not necessary

Comment: @AnirudhR.Huilgol. could you please share sample code.... thanks so much in advance

Comment: @ParmendraSingh sorry wrong URL https://github.com/huilgolAni19/SampleGpsApp this is the actual URL

Comment: Can we get current location (longitude,latitude) in this ?

Comment: @WealInfotech yes you can just go to this link github.com/huilgolAni19/SampleGpsApp you will find the Sample application in which I have shown how to get current latitude longitude

Answer (score 7):

Check the code below. Firstly, it will check if location is enabled or not and will prompt user to enable the location.

```
private GoogleApiClient googleApiClient;

final static int REQUEST_LOCATION = 199;


// check whether gps is enabled
public boolean noLocation() {
        final LocationManager manager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);

        if (!manager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER)) {
            //  buildAlertMessageNoGps();

            enableLoc();
            return true;
        }
        return false;

    }


 private void enableLoc() {

if (googleApiClient == null) {
            googleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
                    .addApi(LocationServices.API)
                    .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
                    .addOnConnectionFailedListener(new GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult connectionResult) {

                            Timber.v("Location error " + connectionResult.getErrorCode());
                        }
                    }).build();
            googleApiClient.connect();

            LocationRequest locationRequest = LocationRequest.create();
            locationRequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY);
            locationRequest.setInterval(30 * 1000);
            locationRequest.setFastestInterval(5 * 1000);
            LocationSettingsRequest.Builder builder = new LocationSettingsRequest.Builder()
                    .addLocationRequest(locationRequest);

            builder.setAlwaysShow(true);

            PendingResult<LocationSettingsResult> result =
                    LocationServices.SettingsApi.checkLocationSettings(googleApiClient, builder.build());
            result.setResultCallback(new ResultCallback<LocationSettingsResult>() {
                @Override
                public void onResult(LocationSettingsResult result) {
                    final Status status = result.getStatus();
                    switch (status.getStatusCode()) {
                        case LocationSettingsStatusCodes.RESOLUTION_REQUIRED:
                            try {
                                // Show the dialog by calling startResolutionForResult(),
                                // and check the result in onActivityResult().
                                status.startResolutionForResult(
                                        (Activity) context, REQUEST_LOCATION);
                            } catch (IntentSender.SendIntentException e) {
                                // Ignore the error.
                            }
                            break;
                    }
                }
            });
        }



        @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

        switch (requestCode) {
            case REQUEST_LOCATION:
                switch (resultCode) {
                    case Activity.RESULT_CANCELED: {
                        // The user was asked to change settings, but chose not to
                        finish();
                        break;
                    }
                    default: {
                        break;
                    }
                }
                break;
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: Answers with code, which is your own code and it's not tutorial, should be provided on StackOverflow with code formatting.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion,will re-post it

Answer (score 1):

I've created a library based on Anirudh answer.

Short guide how to use it:

1. **Add** it to you `build.gradle` file:

   `compile 'net.alexandroid.utils:gps:1.6'`
2. **Implement** `GpsStatusDetectorCallBack` interface.
3. **Implement interface methods**: `onGpsSettingStatus` and `onGpsAlertCanceledByUser`
4. **Create** instance variable:

   ```
   private GpsStatusDetector mGpsStatusDetector;
   ```
5. **Instantiate** it in `onCreate()`:

   ```
    mGpsStatusDetector = new GpsStatusDetector(this);
   ```
6. In place you need to check the status and show a dialog if need **add**:

   ```
   mGpsStatusDetector.checkGpsStatus();
   ```
7. **Override** onActivityResult and add there:

   ```
   mGpsStatusDetector.checkOnActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode);
   ```

---

More information about the library: https://github.com/Pulimet/GpsDetector-Library

---

Example:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements GpsStatusDetector.GpsStatusDetectorCallBack {

    private GpsStatusDetector mGpsStatusDetector;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        mGpsStatusDetector = new GpsStatusDetector(this);
        mGpsStatusDetector.checkLocationSettingStatus();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        mGpsStatusDetector.checkOnActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode);
    }

    @Override
    public void onGpsSettingStatus(boolean enabled) {
        Log.d("TAG", "onGpsSettingStatus: " + enabled);
    }

    @Override
    public void onGpsAlertCanceledByUser() {
        Log.d("TAG", "onGpsAlertCanceledByUser");
    }
}
```

Comment: awesome bro, I didn't know how to make the library with my code please let me know how to do it if you find some leisure time to spend

Comment: Hi, just follow the guide.

Comment: not able to find checkLocationSettingStatus() method in java file

Comment: Use checkGpsStatus() method please. (Answer updated)

Answer (score 1):

Since SettingsApi is deprecated and after checking into the developer site [here](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/location/SettingsClient). I was able to achive the same result as Ola app.

Add the below method in your Activity class

```
private void switchOnGPS() {
    LocationSettingsRequest.Builder builder = new LocationSettingsRequest.Builder()
            .addLocationRequest(new LocationRequest().setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY));

    Task<LocationSettingsResponse> task = LocationServices.getSettingsClient(this).checkLocationSettings(builder.build());
    task.addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<LocationSettingsResponse>() {
        @Override
        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<LocationSettingsResponse> task) {
            try {
                LocationSettingsResponse response = task.getResult(ApiException.class);
            } catch (ApiException e) {
                switch (e.getStatusCode())
                {
                    case LocationSettingsStatusCodes.RESOLUTION_REQUIRED :
                        ResolvableApiException   resolvableApiException = (ResolvableApiException) e;
                        try {
                            resolvableApiException.startResolutionForResult(MainActivity.this,REQUEST_CHECK_SETTINGS);
                        } catch (IntentSender.SendIntentException e1) {
                            e1.printStackTrace();
                        }
                        break;

                        case LocationSettingsStatusCodes.SETTINGS_CHANGE_UNAVAILABLE:
                            //open setting and switch on GPS manually
                            break;
                }
            }
        }
    });
    //Give permission to access GPS
    ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION}, 11);
}
```

Call the above method in your Activity's **onResume** method like below

```
@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    switchOnGPS();
}
```

**Add respective Location permission in Manifest file.**

Answer (score 0):

```
package com.example.user.myGPS;

    import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.content.IntentSender;
    import com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient;
    import com.google.android.gms.common.api.PendingResult;
    import com.google.android.gms.common.api.ResultCallback;
    import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationRequest;
    import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationServices;
    import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationSettingsRequest;
    import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationSettingsResult;
    import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationSettingsStates;
    import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationSettingsStatusCodes;



public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {


    private GoogleApiClient googleApiClient;
    final int REQUEST_CHECK_SETTINGS = 0x1;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        //-------Code to turn on GPS------------------
        if (googleApiClient == null) {

            googleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(MainActivity.this)
                    .addApi(LocationServices.API).build();
            googleApiClient.connect();
            LocationRequest locationRequest = LocationRequest.create();
            locationRequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY);
            locationRequest.setInterval(30 * 1000);
            locationRequest.setFastestInterval(5 * 1000);
            LocationSettingsRequest.Builder builder = new LocationSettingsRequest.Builder().addLocationRequest(locationRequest);
            builder.setAlwaysShow(true);
            builder.setNeedBle(true);


            PendingResult<LocationSettingsResult> result = LocationServices.SettingsApi.checkLocationSettings(googleApiClient, builder.build());
            result.setResultCallback(new ResultCallback<LocationSettingsResult>() {
                @Override
                public void onResult(LocationSettingsResult result) {
                    final com.google.android.gms.common.api.Status status = result.getStatus();
                    final LocationSettingsStates state = result.getLocationSettingsStates();
                    switch (status.getStatusCode()) {
                        case LocationSettingsStatusCodes.SUCCESS:
                            break;
                        case LocationSettingsStatusCodes.RESOLUTION_REQUIRED:
                            try
                            {
                                status.startResolutionForResult(MainActivity.this,REQUEST_CHECK_SETTINGS);
                            } catch (IntentSender.SendIntentException e) {}
                            break;
                        case LocationSettingsStatusCodes.SETTINGS_CHANGE_UNAVAILABLE:
                            break;
                    }
                }
            });

        }


    }


}
```

Comment: Do not forget to add <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/> in android manifest