# How to prompt user to turn on location settings like Google Maps?

Tags: android, google-maps

I'd like to prompt the user to turn on their location settings like Google Maps does when your location settings are off and you want directions. Everything I have found so far just says to direct the user to the locations settings menu using an intent. Does anyone know how to do it like Google Maps does?

Comment: Take a look at this answer, it has a complete implementation for both a Fragment and an Activity: http://stackoverflow.com/a/31816683/4409409

Comment: Can be achieved by calling the LocationSettingsRequest.Builder class provided in Android SDK. For code implementation, take a look at this SO answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29801368/how-to-show-enable-location-dialog-like-google-maps?answertab=votes#tab-top