# How with broadcast receiver should I subscribe to listen for location services change

Tags: android, location, wifi

I am working in an app that manages `wifi` connections, I have the problem that in `android 6.0` the `wifi` scanning is off when the location services are turned off by the user.

What I want is to know if there is an action to which I can subscribe to listen when the user turns off and on the `location services`. I have searched in Android documentation and there are two possible actions, but I am not sure which one to use.

The actions are

```
android.location.PROVIDERS_CHANGED

android.location.MODE_CHANGED
```

The Documentation is not helping me.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get GPS Location in a Broadcast Receiver/or Service to Broadcast Receiver data transfer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7709030/get-gps-location-in-a-broadcast-receiver-or-service-to-broadcast-receiver-data-t)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to? Listen for Location Setting being turned ON (Android App)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36325088/how-to-listen-for-location-setting-being-turned-on-android-app)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is useful when user want to trigger any action on turn On/Off location provides

You should add this action in manifest

```
<action android:name="android.location.PROVIDERS_CHANGED" />
```

and after add this action you can trigger your broadcast receiver

```
<receiver android:name=".GpsLocationReceiver">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.location.PROVIDERS_CHANGED" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

And in your `BroadcastReceiver` class you have to implement `LocationListener` in that class which is given following below..

```
  public class GpsLocationReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {        
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            if (intent.getAction().matches("android.location.PROVIDERS_CHANGED")) {
                Toast.makeText(context, "in android.location.PROVIDERS_CHANGED",
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
           LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
    if( !locationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER) ) {
       //NO GPS
    }else{
//Gps is on
     }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: thanks!, but in the receiver how can i know if the location services are on or off?

Answer (score 0):

Manifest:

```
<action android:name="android.location.PROVIDERS_CHANGED" />


<receiver android:name=".ObserveGpsState">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.location.PROVIDERS_CHANGED" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

And then....

```
   public class ObserveGpsState extends BroadcastReceiver {        
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            if (intent.getAction().matches(LocationManager.PROVIDERS_CHANGED_ACTION)) {
               ......... 
            }
        }
    }
```