# How to check location is on or not while app is running

Tags: android, kotlin, location

I want to check all the time when the app is running, that location of mobile is on or not.
Because I don't want to let client turn the location off when use my application.
I know how to check GPS is on or not for one time but I don't know how to check that all time.

I have checked and searched a lot but I couldn't find anything useful

Comment: Try using pending Intent or services on android.

Comment: @Goutham How? Can you write it here because of two reasons. First I can accept your answer and give you green mark. Second one it's too helpful for me

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to? Listen for Location Setting being turned ON (Android App)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36325088/how-to-listen-for-location-setting-being-turned-on-android-app)