# Android FusedLocation's SettingsApi does not work more than once

Tags: android, google-maps, gps, fusedlocationproviderapi

FusedLocation has a wonderful API to check if the user has enabled all the relevant settings to obtain location. I followed the documentation https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/location/SettingsApi to fire up the SettingsApi. My code to check user's setting is as below

```
private void checkLocationSetting()
{
    if (mLocationSettingsRequest == null)
    {
        mLocationSettingsRequest =
                new LocationSettingsRequest.Builder()
                        .addLocationRequest(mLocationRequest)
                        .setAlwaysShow(true)
                        .build();
    }

    PendingResult<LocationSettingsResult> result =
            LocationServices.SettingsApi.checkLocationSettings(mGoogleApiClient, mLocationSettingsRequest);

    result.setResultCallback(new ResultCallback<LocationSettingsResult>()
    {
        @Override
        public void onResult(LocationSettingsResult result)
        {
            final Status status = result.getStatus();
            final LocationSettingsStates state = result.getLocationSettingsStates();
            switch (status.getStatusCode())
            {
                case LocationSettingsStatusCodes.SUCCESS:
                {
                    // All location settings are satisfied. The client can initialize location
                    // requests here.
                    requestNewLocationBySettingLocationReq();
                    break;
                }
                case LocationSettingsStatusCodes.RESOLUTION_REQUIRED:
                {
                    // Location settings are not satisfied. But could be fixed by showing the user
                    // a dialog.
                    try
                    {
                        // Show the dialog by calling startResolutionForResult(),
                        // and check the result in onActivityResult().
                        status.startResolutionForResult(SpotToiletMap.this, REQUEST_CHECK_SETTINGS);
                    } catch (IntentSender.SendIntentException e)
                    {
                        // Ignore the error.
                    }
                    break;
                }
                case LocationSettingsStatusCodes.SETTINGS_CHANGE_UNAVAILABLE:
                {
                    // Location settings are not satisfied. However, we have no way to fix the
                    // settings so we won't show the dialog.
                    MiscellaneousMethods.showGenericSnackBar(rootView, getString(R.string.location_settings_unavailable));
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    });
}
```

This piece of code works perfectly fine for the first time. Subsequently, the PendingResult CallBack never worked. I was not able to find any logs on logcat as well. For me it looks like an implementation issue.

Here is how to reproduce the issue.

Turn off your GPS. Try to call the method and it perfectly works as expected. It asks me to switch n GPS. Once you receive location update, turn off the GPS again and call this method. I never get a dialog to enable GPS. I call this method on a button click which tries to get the latest location of the user.

EDIT:
I tried to declare PendingResult result as a class variable. Still no luck. I also tried to initialize result only once by checking if it is null, as expected and as mentioned in Google's documentation it throws an exception mentioning the result is already consumed.

Comment: What version of Google Play Services are you using in your app, and what version of Google Play Services do you have installed on the device while testing?

Comment: On my device I have Google play service 9.2.56 and in my app i am using 9.0.2.

Comment: @DanielNugent Now I tried to update my app to use latest 9.2.0 version. Still same issue

Comment: Also, what version on Android on the device?

Comment: i tried on 4.4.2 and 4.4.4,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the problem is that you're not re-creating the `LocationSettingsRequest.Builder` each time, as you only re-create it if it's null.

I got it working, tested on both Android 4.4.4 and 6.0.1.

The dialog is shown each time the button is pressed (provided that Location was disabled on the device between button presses):

```
public void checkLocationSetting() {
    mLocationRequest = LocationRequest.create();
    mLocationRequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY);
    mLocationRequest.setInterval(30 * 1000);
    mLocationRequest.setFastestInterval(5 * 1000);

    LocationSettingsRequest.Builder builder = new LocationSettingsRequest.Builder()
            .addLocationRequest(mLocationRequest);
    builder.setAlwaysShow(true);

    result = LocationServices.SettingsApi.checkLocationSettings(mGoogleApiClient, builder.build());

    result.setResultCallback(new ResultCallback<LocationSettingsResult>() {
        @Override
        public void onResult(LocationSettingsResult result) {
            final Status status = result.getStatus();
            switch (status.getStatusCode()) {
                case LocationSettingsStatusCodes.SUCCESS:
                    // All location settings are satisfied. The client can initialize location
                    // requests here.
                    //...
                    break;
                case LocationSettingsStatusCodes.RESOLUTION_REQUIRED:
                    // Location settings are not satisfied. But could be fixed by showing the user
                    // a dialog.
                    try {
                        // Show the dialog by calling startResolutionForResult(),
                        // and check the result in onActivityResult().
                        status.startResolutionForResult(
                                MainActivity.this,
                                REQUEST_LOCATION);
                    } catch (IntentSender.SendIntentException e) {
                        // Ignore the error.
                    }
                    break;
                case LocationSettingsStatusCodes.SETTINGS_CHANGE_UNAVAILABLE:
                    // Location settings are not satisfied. However, we have no way to fix the
                    // settings so we won't show the dialog.
                    //...
                    break;
            }
        }
    });

}
```

Comment: I tried to re initialize the Builder every time. Still I am not able to get this thing working second time.. In fact I tried on 3 different devices. same result on all 3. I also tried to reinit mLocationRequest .. didn't work either.

Comment: After creating another simple activity without any of my business logic I was able to point out what is the issue. in my onLocationChanged() I stopLocationUpdates. which disconnects mGoogleApiClient.. if mGoogleApiClient is not connected then this will not work.  here is my gist https://gist.github.com/rakesh1988/03cd9f909542f7b078c921093ef9ade9