# onActivityResult() not executing in fragment when i call startResolutionForResult

Tags: android, gps, location, onactivityresult

Problem when i am calling to enable gps programatically using GoogleApiClient into fragment...
My code is..

```
 final Status status = result.getStatus();
                final LocationSettingsStates state = result.getLocationSettingsStates();
                switch (status.getStatusCode())
                {
                    case LocationSettingsStatusCodes.SUCCESS:
                        // All location settings are satisfied. The client can initialize location
                        // requests here.
                        getCurrentLocation();
                        break;
                    case LocationSettingsStatusCodes.RESOLUTION_REQUIRED:
                        // Location settings are not satisfied. But could be fixed by showing the user
                        // a dialog.
                        try {
                            // Show the dialog by calling startResolutionForResult(),
                            // and check the result in onActivityResult().
                            status.startResolutionForResult(getActivity(), REQUEST_ID_GPS_PERMISSIONS);
                        } catch (IntentSender.SendIntentException e) {
                            // Ignore the error.
                        }
                        break;
                    case LocationSettingsStatusCodes.SETTINGS_CHANGE_UNAVAILABLE:
                        // Location settings are not satisfied. However, we have no way to fix the
                        // settings so we won't show the dialog.
                        break;
                }
```

and my onActivityResult is

```
 final Status status = result.getStatus();
                final LocationSettingsStates state = result.getLocationSettingsStates();
                switch (status.getStatusCode())
                {
                    case LocationSettingsStatusCodes.SUCCESS:
                        // All location settings are satisfied. The client can initialize location
                        // requests here.
                        getCurrentLocation();
                        break;
                    case LocationSettingsStatusCodes.RESOLUTION_REQUIRED:
                        // Location settings are not satisfied. But could be fixed by showing the user
                        // a dialog.
                        try {
                            // Show the dialog by calling startResolutionForResult(),
                            // and check the result in onActivityResult().
                            status.startResolutionForResult(getActivity(), REQUEST_ID_GPS_PERMISSIONS);
                        } catch (IntentSender.SendIntentException e) {
                            // Ignore the error.
                        }
                        break;
                    case LocationSettingsStatusCodes.SETTINGS_CHANGE_UNAVAILABLE:
                        // Location settings are not satisfied. However, we have no way to fix the
                        // settings so we won't show the dialog.
                        break;
                }
```

but my onActicvityResult() not executing in fragment.
Where is the problem???
Help me.....Thanks in advance.

Comment: Create an onActivityResult in your Activity class of that fragment and put a debugger there an check

Comment: if you are starting your activity as **getActivity().startActivityForResult(...)**
 replace it with  **startActivityForResult(...);**.

Comment: onActivityResult of Activity executed but when i call any function of fragment from activity always context is null

Comment: @SubhechhuKhanal I'm not calling startActivityForResult, i'm calling startResolutionForResult.

Comment: if your onActivityResult() of activity is being called, aren't you being able to call onActivityResult() of fragment from onActivityResult() of activity?? 

fragment.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data)

Answer (score 13):

**Use this Line for `Fragment` to get result in `onActivityResult`**

```
startIntentSenderForResult(status.getResolution().getIntentSender(), REQUEST_ID_GPS_PERMISSIONS, null, 0, 0, 0, null);
```

**insted of**

```
 status.startResolutionForResult(getActivity(), REQUEST_ID_GPS_PERMISSIONS);
```

Comment: what is issue you face @KonstantinKonopko?,  it works for me very well

Comment: @NikunjParadva this works only when I've added `onActivityResult` to my Fragment and Activity too

Answer (score 12):

As fragments are placed inside activities and their life cycle tightly coupled to the life cycle of the containing activity.

1) In Activity:

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    Fragment frg = getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.fragment_container_main);
    if (frg != null) {
        frg.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    }
}
```

Now container activity of fragment will provide intent data, request code and result to the fragment so to get data and result in fragment you have to override `onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data)` in fragment as well

2) In Fragment

```
@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

}
```

there you will get callback from your parent activity.Do whatever you want to send or to get callback.

Comment: Save my time. Tq.

Comment: This is a good answer but the most accurate would be to replace the `status.startResolutionForResult(getActivity(), REQUEST_ID_GPS_PERMISSIONS);` in your fragment for    `this.startIntentSenderForResult(status.getResolution().getIntentSender(), REQUEST_ID_GPS_PERMISSIONS, null, 0, 0, 0, null);`. That way you will not have to put an onActivityResult in your activity and your fragment would get the result directly

Comment: @JoseJet Brilliant. If you had written yours as answer I'd upvote it.

Comment: @JoseJet This is what exactly I were looking. Thank a ton!

Comment: @JoseJet Your comment saved my day! Thanks a lot. It worked like a charm!

Answer (score 12):

When you need to resolve the `Status` or the `ResolvableApiException`, I suggest you to leverage the `activity.registerForActivityResult` API in place of `startResolutionForResult`:

```
val launcher = activity.registerForActivityResult(ActivityResultContracts.StartIntentSenderForResult()) { result ->
        if (result.resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
            // User accepted
        } else {
            // User didn't accepted
        }
    }

val intentSenderRequest = IntentSenderRequest.Builder(exception.resolution).build()
launcher.launch(intentSenderRequest)
```

Comment: Thanks for the example! Been searching it for hours

Comment: Thanks! I found your deleted answer in https://stackoverflow.com/a/63296989/2914140. It is the only answer that helped me with new API.

Answer (score 3):

I just finished writing some of this same code today. You're on the right track with needing the `onActivityForResult()` method implemented, but unfortunately `startResolutionForResult()` doesn't call back to the fragment; it calls back to the activity that contains the fragment.

You must implement `onActivityResult()` in the calling activity (or wherever your fragments are being managed), and then forward that result to your fragment.

I did something like this in my activities `onActivityResult` (FragmentBase is just the base class I'm using for all my other fragments, make sure you tag your fragments when you add them):

```
@Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data){
        switch (requestCode){
            case LocationHelper.LOCATION_ENABLER_ID:
                FragmentBase mapFrag = (FragmentBase) fragmentManager.findFragmentByTag(FragmentBase.MAP_FRAGMENT);
                ((FragmentMap)mapFrag).returnFromSettings();
                break;
            default:
                super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

**Solution for 2019 [Kotlin] [AndroidX]**

**1. In Your Fragment:**

```
override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent?) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data)
    Log.d(context!!, "onActivityResult: [From Fragment]: " + requestCode + ", " + resultCode)
}
```

**2. In Your Activity:**

```
override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent?) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data)
    Log.d(this, "onActivityResult: [From Activity]:  " + requestCode + ", " + resultCode)
    val navHostFragment = supportFragmentManager.fragments.first() as? NavHostFragment
    if(navHostFragment != null) {
        val childFragments = navHostFragment.childFragmentManager.fragments
        childFragments.forEach { fragment ->
            fragment.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data)
        }
    }
}
```

> This will work if you're using Android Navigation Component.

Answer (score 1):

Follow the below steps :

1 . InActivity :

```
@Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        YourFragment fragment = (YourFragment ) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("TAG_NAME");
        if (fragment != null) {
            fragment .onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        }

    }
```

2. In Fragment

   ```
    @Override
   protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) 
    {
    // Now in fragment will triggger Here you can do work

   }
   ```

Answer (score 0):

If you are running this code in Fragment than don't use startResolutionForResult(). Instead use startIntentSenderForResult(status.getResolution().getIntentSender(), REQUEST_CODE_LOCATION_SETTING, null, 0, 0, 0, null);

and overrider onaActivityResult() in your fragment. Result will be delivered to this method only.