# LocationSettingsRequest does not show permission check dialog

Tags: android, google-play-services, android-permissions, fusedlocationproviderapi

I'm using the **FusedLocationProviderClient** in a project. At the onCreate method I've got this snippet being called:

```
private void setupFusedLocationProvider() {
    LocationSettingsRequest.Builder builder = new LocationSettingsRequest.Builder();
    LocationRequest locationRequest = new LocationRequest();
    locationRequest.setInterval(10000);
    locationRequest.setFastestInterval(5000);
    locationRequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY);
    builder.addLocationRequest(locationRequest);
    builder.setAlwaysShow(true);

    SettingsClient client = LocationServices.getSettingsClient(this);
    Task<LocationSettingsResponse> task = client.checkLocationSettings(builder.build());

    task.addOnSuccessListener(this, locationSettingsResponse -> locationPermissionsSatisfied());

    task.addOnFailureListener(this, e -> {
        if (e instanceof ResolvableApiException) {
            try {
                ResolvableApiException resolvable = (ResolvableApiException) e;
                resolvable.startResolutionForResult(Activity.this,
                        REQUEST_CHECK_LOCATION_SETTINGS);
            } catch (IntentSender.SendIntentException sendEx) {
                //Ignore
            }
        }
    });
}
```

The problem is that, even with a cache wipe or uninstall, the app does not show a dialog to request for proper location permissions settings: the **onSuccessListener** is being called everytime (while the location premissions are not set). I'm using the latest google services apis.

My manifest contains these 2:

```
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
```

Comment: possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31235564

Comment: @noogui I'm not using googleapi client, just the fused location providers

Comment: @Zarkopafilis did you manage to fix this? On what android version did you tested? I have the same issue on Android 9 and 10