# How to get location from background service when location is turned off?

Tags: android, location

I am using a location callback for saving the location of the user but when the location is turned off there is not data of location received. Is there any way to tackle this problem i.e. to get data while the location is turned off or turning on the location programmatically from background service?

Comment: `to get data while the location is turned off` perhaps the user doesn't want you to get their location if it's off ?

Comment: Now wouldn't that be a serious breach of user privacy?

Comment: [LocationSettingsRequest dialog to enable GPS - onActivityResult() skipped](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31235564/3290339)

Comment: @linuxartisan I'm just asking that if a user gives permission "allow all the time" then is it possible to get the data when the location is off?