# startIntentSenderForResult deprecated Android

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity

Code snippet:

```
private fun requestHint() {
    val hintRequest = HintRequest.Builder()
        .setPhoneNumberIdentifierSupported(true)
        .build()
    val credentialsClient = Credentials.getClient(this)
    val intent = credentialsClient.getHintPickerIntent(hintRequest)
    try {
        startIntentSenderForResult(
            intent.intentSender,
            CREDENTIAL_PICKER_REQUEST,
            null, 0, 0, 0
        )
    } catch (e: IntentSender.SendIntentException) {
        e.printStackTrace()
    }
}
```

I tried to resolve this, from [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/activity/result/contract/ActivityResultContracts.StartIntentSenderForResult) but I didn't understand

If anyone knows how to resolve it please help
Thanks

Answer (score 16):

Use the below code -

```
private fun showPhoneNumberSuggestion() {

    val hintRequest = HintRequest.Builder()
        .setPhoneNumberIdentifierSupported(true)
        .build()

    val options = CredentialsOptions.Builder()
        .forceEnableSaveDialog()
        .build()

    // Then pass the hint request object to
    // credentialsClient.getHintPickerIntent()
    // to get an intent to prompt the user to
    // choose a phone number.

    val credentialClient = Credentials.getClient(applicationContext, options)
    val intent = credentialClient.getHintPickerIntent(hintRequest)
    try {

        val intentSenderRequest = IntentSenderRequest.Builder(intent.intentSender).build()
        phonePickIntentResultLauncher.launch(intentSenderRequest)

    } catch (e: IntentSender.SendIntentException) {
        e.printStackTrace()
    }
}
```

For ActivityResult, use -

```
private val phonePickIntentResultLauncher =
    registerForActivityResult(ActivityResultContracts.StartIntentSenderForResult()) { result ->
        if (result != null) {
            val intent = result.data
            val credential = intent?.getParcelableExtra<Credential>(Credential.EXTRA_KEY)
            binding.inputPhone.setText(credential?.id)
        }
    }
```

Remember there are no request codes.

Use different result launchers for every particular task.

**Update 2023:**

The before mentioned method is now deprecated.

Now to retrieve the PhoneNumber, we must use [`SignInClient`](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/auth/api/identity/SignInClient) like this,

```
private fun showPhoneNumberSuggestion() {
    val signInClient = Identity.getSignInClient(this)
    signInClient.getPhoneNumberHintIntent(GetPhoneNumberHintIntentRequest.builder().build())
        .addOnCanceledListener {

        }
        .addOnSuccessListener {
            val intentSenderRequest = IntentSenderRequest.Builder(it).build()
            phonePickIntentResultLauncher.launch(intentSenderRequest);
        }
        .addOnFailureListener {

        }
}

private val phonePickIntentResultLauncher =
    registerForActivityResult(ActivityResultContracts.StartIntentSenderForResult()) { result ->
        if (result != null) {
            val intent = result.data
            val phoneNumber = intent!!.getStringExtra("phone_number_hint_result")
        }
    }
```

Make sure to import everything from this package, `com.google.android.gms.auth.api`

Comment: This is not working in android 12.   Getting this error.
```Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: com.getvisitapp.android.debug: Targeting S+ (version 31 and above) requires that one of FLAG_IMMUTABLE or FLAG_MUTABLE be specified when creating a PendingIntent.
    Strongly consider using FLAG_IMMUTABLE, only use FLAG_MUTABLE if some functionality depends on the PendingIntent being mutable, e.g. if it needs to be used with inline replies or bubbles.
```
How to set `FLAG_IMMUTABLE` flag here?

Comment: @Chinmay have got any update for the issue mentioned above?

Comment: I have not got any update regarding this issue till now.

Comment: According to the docs: https://developer.android.com/about/versions/12/behavior-changes-12#pending-intent-mutability

"Strongly consider using FLAG_IMMUTABLE, only use FLAG_MUTABLE if some functionality depends on the PendingIntent being mutable, e.g. if it needs to be used with inline replies or bubbles."

I would suggest you use FLAG_IMMUTABLE unless it is specifically documented that your PendingIntent needs to be mutable. 

In my code, I have both. The PendingIntent for geofencing is mutable as given in those documents. For push notifications it is FLAG_IMMUTABLE.

Comment: @Chinmay can u sort out this issue?

Comment: @Liya, answer is now updated.

Comment: @Chinmay, answer is now updated